# How to disable the "Press M-x..." title line of org-search-view command's output?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I use GNU Emacs 26.1 and want to remove the following enormous message

```
Press ‘M-x org-agenda-manipulate-query-add’, ‘M-x org-agenda-manipulate-query-subtract’ to add/sub word, ‘M-x org-agenda-manipulate-query-add-re’, ‘M-x org-agenda-manipulate-query-subtract-re’ to add/sub regexp, ‘C-u r’ to edit
```

from the `*Org Agenda*` buffer, which appears after `org-search-view` command.

Comment: I'm guessing that those commands are normally bound to keys in the usual context where that msg is shown, in which case the msg would not be so "enormous". Do you not want those commands bound to keys in your environment, i.e., did you intentionally remove those bindings (e.g. to bind other commands instead)? If not then maybe see why the commands are not bound in this case. (E.g., do you see the same thing if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q`?)

Comment: (In any case, hopefully someone will answer your question of how to prevent that message.)

Comment: Hi, regarding 'emacs -Q' command for some reason it's broken on my machine (I installed emacs via `brew cask install emacs`)

Comment: if `emacs -Q` is broken on your system, that suggests something is wrong with your installation. The easiest way to fix something at that level is probably to re-install.

Answer (score 1):

### Short Summary

You can't turn off the message itself without changing the code that produces it. You *can* shorten it by binding the commands commands mentioned to other keys, the default bindings being ‘[’, ‘]’, ‘{’, ‘}’ and ‘C-u r’ respectively. In your case, all but the last one seem to be unbound for some reason, you may want to inspect the reason why.

### Long Version

Inspection of the source code of `org-search-view` reveals

```
(unless org-agenda-multi
      (insert (substitute-command-keys "\
Press `\\[org-agenda-manipulate-query-add]', \
`\\[org-agenda-manipulate-query-subtract]' to add/sub word, \
`\\[org-agenda-manipulate-query-add-re]', \
`\\[org-agenda-manipulate-query-subtract-re]' to add/sub regexp, \
`\\[universal-argument] \\[org-agenda-redo]' to edit\n"))
      (add-text-properties pos (1- (point))
                   (list 'face 'org-agenda-structure)))
```

The only way to turn of the message once this function is invoked, is therefore
to bind `org-agenda-multi` to some truthy value before invoking it. This happens in `org-agenda-append-agenda` and `org-agenda-run-series`. The former appears to be triggered by pressing "A" in the agenda buffer, whereas the latter seems to be run somewhere by `org-agenda`. However, simply doing that leads to even worse consequences than inserting the string, as it also affects behaviour elsewhere in org-agenda.el, therefore I can't really recommend that.

Knowing this, you might want to bind the functions mentioned to other keys, so as to shorten the message. Just for reference, the default keybindings lead to the message

```
Press ‘[’, ‘]’ to add/sub word, ‘{’, ‘}’ to add/sub regexp, ‘C-u r’ to edit
```

so it is likely, that something went wrong somewhere else in your setup. Have a look at the variable `org-agenda-keymap` and where it might be modified by one of your scripts.
Assuming you don't want to change these bindings, you will have to redefine `org-search-view`, replacing `org-agenda-multi` by an expression allowing customization like `(or org-agenda-multi some-fresh-variable)`, or wrapping just the insert or something like that. It would be best to do so in your init file in an `(eval-after-load "org-agenda" ...)` form and using an override advice to achieve this.

Comment: @Lord Yuuma, thank you for your research, I've tried to set `(setq-default org-agenda-multi t)` to my init.el, but as you mentioned it leads to undesired consequences: jump into the search result doesn't work, the fullscreen frame appears instead of half bottom.

Comment: @Drew I've added a summary now. Maybe that helps?

Comment: @IlliaDanko I think within org-agenda `org-agenda-multi` is only ever bound to `t` once the buffer is already set up. It is not a variable meant for customization and you should revert that change to your init file. As I said in my answer, try binding these keys in `org-agenda-keymap` or removing the insert from the code.